# setText in Navigation Drawer

Tags: java, android, settext, android-navigationview

How to set text to view from drawer header layout in navigation drawer ?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

[...]

 NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
 navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
 TextView name = findViewById(R.id.username);
 name.setText(R.string.af_anasayfa_af_butonu);

}
```

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(int)' on a null object
>   reference ..

Comment: Are you sure your `TextView` has an id of `username` indeed?

Comment: @user3738870 Yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
TextView name = (TextView) navigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.username);
```

Comment: @JavaOgreniyor You are welcome, could you upvote or accept my answer, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

use this to change the text of material Drawer

```
navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setTitle("any text");
```

or

```
navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_calculator).setTitle("xxx");
```

Secondly your method of getting string is also not right the right way is

```
String s= getResources().getString(R.string.appbar_scrolling_view_behavior);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
TextView name = findViewById(R.id.username);
```

this is wrong because username is in the navigationHeader and not in view

so, you should to get NavigationHeader and then get  username
for example

```
TextView name = navigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.username);
```